# Background Image blinks (making it so that background shows for a split second) on reload using Flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, background-image

So I have problems with my background image flickering when I refresh. This only happens with Chrome/Edge, but works fine in Firefox...

CSS:

```
.site {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -moz-box-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  /*width: 100vw;*/
  margin: 0;
}

.site-content {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -moz-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
}

.background-image {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  filter: blur(5px);
  background: #4c6c87 url("background.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-top {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid-bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body class="site">
  <header class="top">
    <div class="container grid-top">
      <h1>PlaceHolder</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main class="center site-content">
    <div class="background-image scrollable"></div>
    <h3 class="leftSlide">PlaceHolder</h3>
  </main>
  <footer class="bottom">
    <div class="container grid-bottom">
      <h1>PlaceHolder</h1>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
```

I have tried preloading the background with some JS.. however that didn't work..

JS:

```
var a = new Image();

var img = "background.png";

a.onload = function() {

    document.querySelector('.background-image').style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + img + ')';
}

a.src = img;
```

I'd appreciate any insight.
Thanks~~

Comment: tested on chrome Version 52.0.2743.116 . No flickering..however i did see a blue background color for a short period before the image is loaded...what browser version are you using?

Comment: Yeah, the blue background was talking about (sorry for being unclear). However, this doesn't happen with Firefox though, so its bugging me a lot. And I'm using Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) just in case if that helps.

Comment: What about taking out that background blue color and simpy add the image when fully loaded...you want a demo like this?

Comment: If you mean this "background-image: url("background.png");", on reload you can still see the white background for a short period before the image is loaded. If this isn't what you meant, then sure I'd love a demo!

Comment: I see what you mean...thats tough buddy..it takes javascript time to load that image..GET REQUEST to the server time  plus the time to inject the background. During that time you may want to display a transparent background in the meantime.....

Comment: Another way is to use a base64 string of the image embedded in the browser..but this makes your html look ugly if the string is HUGE